# How to make the height of the two ListView controls to fit UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

The layout posted below creates the the UI. I currently get a result as shown in a.png  and c.png (there is a lot of empty space), but I hope to achieve something similar to b.png and d.png. How can I do this?

I want the height of `lvReceiver` and `lvOnlyOrExcept` to increase and decrease automatically by the rows of data.

What I get now looks like this:

**a.png**

[image: current result]

**c.png**

[image: current result]

What I want it to look like:

**b.png**

[image: desired result]

**d.png**

[image: desired result]

The layout used is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/border_ui" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a15284e3e927f18"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="false" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"  
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRuleNameTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rule Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRuleName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Rule Name" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutChecked"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutName"  
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEnabledRule"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enabled Rule" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chEnabledRule"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutOption"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutChecked"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvReceiveTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Receive Number" />

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvReceiver"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
   /> 

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOptionTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forward Option" />

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvOnlyOrExcept"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#DCDCDC"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Edit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Close" />
</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot when there are multiple items in each list view, please?
The first thing that comes to mind is - try setting the `android:dividerHeight="1.0dp"` and `android:padding="0dp"` inside your `ListView`

Comment: I have posted. Thanks!

Comment: please can you expain it properly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml which you are inflating for the list views must be having excess padding/margin. Please post the xml which you are using to inflate for both the list views. The issue lies there